# Workaround: Customers might be able to avoid the aforementioned errors by using connection policy redirect

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

we have sql-server hosted on azure (East-US zone). for some reason the azure sql database service went down for hours.
Received a message from Microsoft saying

`Workaround: Customers might be able to avoid the aforementioned errors by using connection policy redirect.`

What does this mean and how to set this up?

Answer (score 0):

I can't fully answer because you are probably dealing with the same azure US east incident my team is, but we believe it is related to policies documented here.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/connectivity-architecture?view=azuresql

> Redirect (recommended): Clients establish connections directly to the node hosting the database, leading to reduced latency and improved throughput. For connections to use this mode, clients need to:
> Allow outbound communication from the client to all Azure SQL IP addresses in the region on ports in the range of 11000 to 11999. Use the Service Tags for SQL to make this easier to manage.
> Allow outbound communication from the client to Azure SQL Database gateway IP addresses on port 1433.
> When using the Redirect connection policy, refer to the Azure IP Ranges and Service Tags – Public Cloud for a list of your region's IP addresses to allow.

> Proxy: In this mode, all connections are proxied via the Azure SQL Database gateways, leading to increased latency and reduced throughput. For connections to use this mode, clients need to allow outbound communication from the client to Azure SQL Database gateway IP addresses on port 1433.
> When using the Proxy connection policy, refer to the Gateway IP addresses list later in this article for your region's IP addresses to allow.

> Default: This is the connection policy in effect on all servers after creation unless you explicitly alter the connection policy to either Proxy or Redirect. The default policy is Redirect for all client connections originating inside of Azure (for example, from an Azure Virtual Machine) and Proxy for all client connections originating outside (for example, connections from your local workstation).

I realize this isn't a great quality SO response. I'm adding information quickly rather than emphasizing quality since there is a context of timeliness involved.

FWIW when my team tested in a dev environment that was affected by changing our server policy from Default to Redirect, it improved our database connections from outside azure but made them worse from within Azure.